# Push changes without updating Parse Server version

Tags: parse-platform

I haven't touched my Parse server in almost a year, but today I had to upload new push notification certificates to keep everything running. I added the new p12 certificates (without changing anything else), pushed the changes to Heroku, and immediately started getting an "[Error]: unauthorized (Code: 0, Version: 1.13.0)" message in my console. In my Heroku logs, I was getting code 403 for every push I tried to send using Cloud code. I could still access my dashboard and view data, etc. So it seems like my Cloud code is just broken in some way.

I noticed that my Parse Server version jumped from 2.2.16 to 2.2.25 after pushing these changes. When I reverted the changes and went back to 2.2.16, everything started working again.

Is there a way to require a specific version of Parse Server so I can just keep using 2.2.16 and get these new certificates uploaded? Or, failing that, is there some way to push the certificates to Heroku without updating the Parse Server to a new version?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the 'parse-server' version in package.json to '2.2.16' from '~2.2.16' appears to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Note that `~2.2.16` means to use the latest version `2.2.x` where x >= 16.  `^2.2.16` would mean to use the latest version `2.x.y` where `x.y` >= `2.16`. In the latter case, the y could be < 16, as long as the x is > 2.   If you need an exact version, you must enter that exact version. You can also denote these as `2.2.x` in your package.json to see the same effects. Generally speaking, the patch updates (last number) should be for bug/security fixes and minor tweaks. The minor version (middle number) should be for backwards compatible updates (i.e. new features).

Comment: The major version (first number) is for backwards incompatible changes. Often some core API changes, and lots of deprecated functions. In most cases, it's OK to use ~ to get those bug fixes without having to do any extra work. Though, obviously, there are cases where this could still break your functionality. An explicit version is the safest, though you'd want to subscribe to updates on those modules, so you can test new version and make sure you get all those security patches and don't end up with known vulnerabilities in your app.